# script file: name editing and renaming using PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, renaming

Does anyone know much about powershell?

I have about 3k files i want to edit the name of.. for example

`90_12200.jpg`

to

`12200p.jpg`

anyone know?

Comment: What are the exact renaming rules? Apparently you wish to remove "90_" and add "p" to the name. Is this all you need? Any exceptions?

Comment: yes that's all that needs to be done really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Get-Child item with recursive option to load all the jpg files and rename it using Rename-item command.

```
Get-ChildItem -r -path "C:\test" *.jpg | % { if(!$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.Name.Contains('_')) {Rename-item $_.FullName ( $_.BaseName.Split('_')[1] +"p" + $_.Extension) } }
```

Answer (score 0):

Generate some test files first:

```
0..4 | % { set-content 90_1220$_.jpg "" }
# Output
90_12200.jpg
90_12201.jpg
90_12202.jpg
90_12203.jpg
90_12204.jpg
```

Then list the files, pass to foreach and rename. `$($_.BaseName.Replace("90_", "")+"p"+$_.Extension)` will take the base name, remove 90_, add letter p and file's extension.

```
gci 90_*.jpg | % { Move-Item $_ $($_.BaseName.Replace("90_", "")+"p"+$_.Extension) }
gci
# Output
12200p.jpg
12201p.jpg
12202p.jpg
12203p.jpg
12204p.jpg
```